# Is it "In an interview Tuesday" or " In a Tuesday interview"?

Tags: word-order

I was reading a newspaper that includes an article that starts with **"In an interview Tuesday"**. It baffled me as to how this is correct as it should have been "**In a Tuesday interview**". I know the common usage tells us to place these time/day references first such as "**Tomorrow's meetings**" "**Tuesday morning**". How come does the original partial sentence not follow this format?

Comment: I think it is to save space/character count and to put emphasis on the activity (which is'interview') rather than the day when it was held. i.e., "In an interview [last] Tuesday" (But there might be other better explanation and this is just an opinion)

Comment: It actually conveys this: "In an interview **on** Tuesday." The "on" is omitted. _Journalese_ will often present usages that are unusual, colloquial, or just plain strange. This one is just an idiomatic usage. There is no _Official Omnipotent Authority_ to enforce any "rules." Media can print or say whatever they want in any way they choose.

Answer (score 1):

In American English, but not in British English (to my knowledge), one can say *Tuesday* (which functions as an adverb of time) and one is not required to say *on Tuesday* (a prepositional phrase conveying the same meaning).

Many dictionaries will list the days of the week only as nouns, but [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/tuesday) does list *Tuesday* as an adverb equivalent to *on Tuesday*:

> ADVERB
>
> *chiefly North American*
>   1 On Tuesday:
>   'they’re all leaving Tuesday'